# Converting a maven project to gradle - task init doesn't exist

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have a java-maven project. I want to convert it to gradle so I did:

```
gradle init --type pom
```

And I got an error:

```
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

* What went wrong:
Task 'init' not found in root project 'my-project'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.78 secs
```

I have the last version of gradle:

```
$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Monday, September 9, 2013 8:44:25 PM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on April 8 2014
Ivy: non official version
JVM: 1.7.0_51 (Oracle Corporation 24.51-b03)
OS: Linux 3.13.0-24-generic amd64
```

Comment: I can't answer your question, but you have far from the last version of Gradle. They are at version 2.4 at this time. Check if this works better in that version (http://gradle.org/).

Comment: @Jolta, how come? I installed it just yesterday by apt-get install.

Comment: [Download gradle](http://gradle.org/downloads/) and don't use apt-get...

Comment: Your apt repo is obviously not current.

Comment: I have no idea which one you're using. You didn't even specify what linux distro you're using. Anyway, it doesn't matter, you just need to download Gradle off of their web site.

Comment: In my case, I couldn't even create a new project with gradle 1.4 on my Ubuntu 14.04 (using `apt-get install gradle`) using `gradle init --type java-library`. I tried the same thing with gradle 2.7 and it worked. Something's amiss with gradle 1.4. BTW, the other tasks (e.g., `gradle build`) on gradle 1.4 seem to be fine, but I haven't tested it exhaustively.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that you don't have a multi-project build? Specifically, be sure that you haven't already init a gradle project in the directory one level above.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks Tadeusz, but I don't understand why you claim my answer to be useless. The question/problem was: gradle init task not found. My response was to make sure that no gradle project was initialized in the directory above. I faced exactly the same situation, and the solution was as I wrote above.

Answer (score 2):

To complete mate00's answer... Let's say "my-project" is the sub-project that fails on init. If you have a multi-project build and you have the line `include 'my-project'` in the main project's settings.gradle file, it will throw this error.

The solution is to comment out `include 'my-project'` in the main projects settings.gradle, run the init command on my-project, and then uncomment that line.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Debian. I installed gradle using apt-get. It installed version 1.5. (it was built in 2014)

Then I [installed gradle manually](https://gradle.org/install#manually), and now it works fine.